# Craft multi-site enable password protection

Tags: craft3, multi-site, multi-environment, multi-domain

I have a multi-site Craft CMS set up with 6 sites. I am planning to live only 5 sites and I need to keep the 1 site in development phase. Also I want to enable fron-end password protection for the dev site. DO we have any option to do this i craft CMS, please guide/assists and new to craft cms

-John

Answer (score 1):

The free [Knock-Knock plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/knock-knock) should be perfect for this.

Like Craft itself, the plugin supports [multi-environment configuration](https://github.com/verbb/knock-knock#configuration). And, it’s possible to [configure it per site](https://github.com/verbb/knock-knock#multi-site-configuration), as well.

Comment: Thank you Mats, will try this on the site